# How to add an integer into this Regex in Python without hard coding the integer?

Tags: python, regex

I want to eventually be able to increment an integer within my Regex, but the braces are preventing me from doing so.

So far I have:

```
start = 6
m = re.search(r"(.{{n},}).*?\1".format(n=start), s)
return m.group(1)
```

However, I get `ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a different method of string formatting:

```
m = re.search(r"({.%s,}).*?\1" % start, s)
```

Comment: D'oh, thanks for that. Completely forgot about that usage...